# Implicit Invocation, Deep Links and Session Entities on Actions and DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to enable implicit invocation ("deep links") for my actions which are based on DialogFlow conversational model.

I cannot figure out how to make implicit invocation recognize session entities.

For example, I have an intent which is triggered by the following training phrase:

```
What is the status of the panel <xxx>?
```

where `<xxx>` is mapped to a session entity.

Session entities are pushed to DialogFlow servers upon the first intent request (that is, when receiving the first webhook call for the conversation).

While the intent works well AFTER invoking the app via `Ok Google, talk to <invocation words>`, I cannot make THIS work:

```
Ok Google, talk to <invocation> and ask what is the status of the panel <xxx>
```

because when the intent webhook request is called, the session entity parameter is simply empty, since session entities get populated after DialogFlow matches the intent and calls the webhook.

Is there a way to have session entities pushed somewhere in between?
How do you manage to have deep links work with session entities?

Comment: When you invoke the action for the first time, at what point would there be the opportunity to add session entities? Would it be possible to add some additional training phrases where <xxx> is of type @sys.any, and then you can do a match for either parameter in your fulfillment?

Comment: @NickFelker unfortunately I cannot use `@sys.any`, as many training phrases are much more complex than the example in my original question. For instance, one actual phrase would be: `Raise the temperature by <delta> degrees on <thermostat> for <panel>` or `Turn on the <output_name> in <location> on <panel>`.
As to adding session entities, I am doing that at the very first webhook call I receive (as soon as I can identify the user involved in the conversation), but it's too late anyway, because DialogFlow has already made its decision about matching the intent and filling parameters...